# Redis-om redis node js createEntity

Tags: javascript, redis, schema

It is possible to use the libary redis-om create own keyname with node js?
I try to save slug as keyname but i cant do that.

My Schema:

```html
import { Entity, Schema } from "redis-om";
import client from "../redis.js";

class Person extends Entity {}
export const personSchema = new Schema(
  Person,
  {
    firstName: { type: "string" },
    lastName: { type: "string" },
    age: { type: "number" },
    verified: { type: "boolean" },
  },
  {
    dataStructure: "JSON",
  }
);
export const personRepository = client.fetchRepository(personSchema);
```

Try this in controller and it didn;t work. CreateIndex() also didnt work :-(

```html
import expressAsyncHandler from "express-async-handler";
import { personRepository } from "../models/personModel.js";

export const creatingPerson = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const person = personRepository.createEntity(req.params.id);
  const newPerson = await person.createAndSave(req.body);
  res.status(200).json({ newPerson });
});
```

So it is possible to use slug as keyname with redis-om? for example Person:001

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base on document about [schemaoptions](https://github.com/redis/redis-om-node/blob/main/docs/README.md#schemaoptions) you can customise key name like you want

1. prefix

> The string that comes before the ID when creating Redis keys for
> Entities. Defaults to the class name of the Entity. Combined with the
> results of idStrategy to generate a key. If prefix is Foo and
> idStrategy returns 12345 then the generated key would be Foo:12345

2. idStrategy

> A function that generates a random Entity ID. Defaults to a function that generates ULIDs. Combined with prefix to generate a Redis key. If prefix is Foo and idStratgey returns 12345 then the generated key would be Foo:12345.

```
const myIDGeneratorFunc = (): string => "123";

class Person extends Entity { }
export const personSchema = new Schema(
    Person,
    {
        firstName: { type: "string" },
        lastName: { type: "string" },
        age: { type: "number" },
        verified: { type: "boolean" },
    },
    {
        dataStructure: "JSON",
        prefix: "Person",
        idStrategy: myIDGeneratorFunc,
    }
);
```